# Adding or replacing slide numbering in selected slides' titles

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to create macro that will add to the end of the selected slides' titles numbering in format (1/5).

I have manage to write that part with adding numbering. I am not able to prepare vba for looking for and replacing existing numbering. It is needed when, for whatever reason, the slide order will be changed and needs to be updated.

```vb
Sub SlideNumbering()

Dim shp As shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim SldAll As Single
Dim SldNr As Single

SldAll = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Count

SldNr = SldAll

For s = SldAll To 1 Step -1
    ActivePresentation.Slides(s).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter " (" & SldNr & "/" & SldAll & ")"
    SldNr = SldNr - 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The simplest way to handle that situation is to write a separate mecro that erases all numbering. Then your macro always starts with a blank canvas.

Comment: Ok but still I do not know how to do it if I don't know the number How select text range in string that has "(" ")"and unknown content between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a macro to delete the existing numbering. This uses a regex pattern to find a sequence of a space, a bracket, any number, a backslash, any number and a closing bracket:

```
Sub DeleteNumbering()
  Dim regX As Object
  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim oShape As Shape
  Dim Foundb As Boolean
  Dim NewText$

  Set regX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  With regX
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = " \(\d(/)\d\)"
  End With
  ReplaceWord = ""

  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
      If oShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        If (oShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderCenterTitle _
        Or oShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderTitle) _
        And oShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
          Foundb = regX.Test(oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
          If Foundb = True Then
            NewText$ = regX.Replace(oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "")
            oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = NewText$
          End If
        End If
      End If
    Next oShape
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```